# Pros and cons of placing test files in the same folder as source files, or separate under test/

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing

What are the advantages and disadvantages of placing test files next to the source files they test (in the same `src` directory), vs. in a separate `tests` directory, mirroring the `src` hierarchy?

Having them in the same folder seems to make life easier when it comes to maintenance, but also crowds the source directories.

**Option 1:** Directory structure when having separate folders for source and tests:

```
- src
+-- item.ts
`-- util
    +-- helper.ts

- test
+-- item.test.ts
`-- util
    `-- helper.test.ts
```

**Option 2:** Directory structure when having both types of files in the same directory:

```
- src
+-- item.ts
+-- item.test.ts
`-- util
    +-- helper.ts
    `-- helper.test.ts
```

I used to always go with option 1 until trying out `angular-cli` and having it generate code files alongside the test files as in option 2, which made me rethink the whole thing.

Comment: First, Based on DRY, the option 2 help us don't make 2 changes if there are any directory name changes. 
Second, Personally, I like option 2 because it's much easier for TDD.

Comment: @DavidGuan That makes sense, but it does make the code less "organized", in a sense. I feel like the directory naming wouldn't be an issue if there was some tooling to mirror directory structure.

Comment: I'd say option 1, although you do end up repeating yourself it makes your builds easier/faster as you can just ignore one folder instead of having to check every file, but that may only be milliseconds. I don't think it makes a huge amount of difference, so just go with what you feel works best with you.

Comment: Option 2 with a little tweak: Create a `__test__` subdirectory within the directory which contains the files to be unit tested and put the tests in that directory. This way you don't pollute the directory view, yet you still keep the tests close by. I.e. `src/api/users.ts` and `src/api/__test__/users.test.ts` and you can conveniently collapse/expand the test folder as you need.

Answer (score 52):

Option #2 is the way I'd go.

When thinking about the Angular 2 components, I consider them to be a single entity, made up of multiple files. You don't move your HTML / CSS files out to some other directory, away from the component, so why move the unit tests?

I've written a small utility plugin for VSCode that I personally find quite useful - it compresses an Angular 2 component into a single entry on the Explorer view, and adds icons / context menu options for getting to the template / css / unit tests. This helps me see the component as a single unit, comprising multiple parts. Maybe something like that would help keep your directory "clean" if that's what you worry about?

I would encourage you to think about unit tests as PART OF your code, rather than in addition to. They'll be very useful if you can keep on top of them.

Comment: My question isn't specific to Angular 2 at all.

Comment: In that case it's surely just preference

Comment: Upvoted for _"think about unit tests as PART of your code"_

Comment: Then where will you put the test related sources? For example, test mock file?

Comment: In my Angular apps I keep my common mock files located under `/src/test/` because that's alongside the `test.ts` file which is used to collect all the tests together. You just have to make sure to exclude the directory in your tsconfig.json

Comment: What's the plugin called? I'd love to try it.

Comment: "so why move the unit tests?" because they are not required to produce or render the component in a web browser, unlike the other files you mentioned. This nuance is important and why I disagree with this answer.

Comment: I agree, I've been using Option #1 for the last few years and it does NOT scale well into large code bases.

With Option#1 your test folder hierarchy has to mirror the same structure as your src code structure.  This is okay for small projects.  But for large refactoring s its very difficult to keep that mirror structure correct.   With Option #1 whenever you move source code folders around, the tests move with them.  Much more efficient.

Comment: Things that update at the same time and same reason should be physically close to each other in the folder structure.

Since the test driven development involved a TON of switching back and forth between the test file and the src file,  I think a considerable speedup would come about from placing the test file right next to the src file.

When deploying the code,  just make sure all your .spec files are pulled out, that all.

For end to end tests, I would create a separate test folder for that,  at the top level,  since it is testing the entire system.

Answer (score 42):

My personal recommendation is to go with #1. The reasons are:

1. Your source code is not 'polluted' with code that is not related to actual business logic. Mind that it is not so uncommon to have more than one test file for the same class/module.
2. There are more that just unit tests you are probably going to write. What about e2e? Are they going to be placed along side corresponding 'something', as they are not so bound to the particular file? So you risk end up cluttering your tests over whole project - some of them in one place and some in other. Separation of all tests in the dedicated directory - solves this issue.
3. Its easy to prepare the deploy of the project. Otherwise you will have to somehow strip out all tests from the transpiled sources.

Do not trust me on this - have a look at the established projects like

- [React](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react/src)
- [Angular2](https://github.com/angular/angular.js)

Comment: I have to disagree here: even the Angular 2 project itself sets up this way. Tests don't "pollute" your code. Tests ARE your code. Unit tests for individual components are useful, and rather than keeping a mirror of your main code directory solely for tests, you can find the unit test you're looking for right there where you'd expect it.

Comment: We are talking different things. I would really like not to go into wars what approach it "the one" therefore my answer starts with "My personal recommendation". Regarding angular2 - just by taking the first folder from their git repository: https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/%40angular/animation we see clear separation of tests and sorce code into two distinct nested folders. And the same for each "module".

Comment: That's a fair point. I hadn't noticed that the Angular project itself differed from the CLI project. I wonder what the rationale for that is. I agree that this is mostly opinion-based, but the OP mentioned they're using Angular-CLI, and sticking to conventions in that regard will be beneficial in the long run (considering upgrades etc)

Comment: Further to this, point #2: e2e ARE separated in the Angular-CLI project, so this is taken care of (since e2e don't correspond to a specific component). #3: the .spec.ts files are already removed from the output JS so this isn't an issue the OP has to be aware of.

Comment: My opinion: I prefer #1 because #2 makes my eyes work harder.  With # 2, the spec files slow me down when I am looking for a component file to click on.   The name of the spec file is so similar, unless I slow down and read carefully,  I will click on the spec file name instead of the component file name.  This wastes my time.   This is significant because I will work with the component file many more times than the spec file.

Comment: personal preferations aside, your tests are part of your business logic (#1). You can see your tests as the definitions of the business rules and your production code as their implementations. 
When I take a first look at a project I mostly look at the tests as they explain the code better than the code itself sometimes does (assuming they are well written).
For #2, you put e2e tests in a seperate folder, as you would do now. I Don't see the problem in combining both philosophies?
#3 Adding 1 extra exclusion in your build config doesn't seem like a lot of work to me :)

Comment: I think only #2 is a valid argument here, and that can be solved by having e2e tests in a separate directory, while unit tests are next to their files, thus showing what has and what doesn't have a test, and making it easier to move/rename test files when source files (inevitably) get moved or renamed.

Comment: #3 it depends on your build setup. At worst, you can exclude *.test.js from the pipeline. In more modern build setups with tree-shaking, you don't even have to think about it.

Comment: This answer has more concrete rationale than the others. I wish it was upvoted higher. Additionally, this approach keeps test helper code out of your source code and ultimately your bundled application. E.g. you might end up writing testUtils.ts with a method to generate dummy data. You'll need to either follow a naming convention to exclude these sorts of files from the build or you can simply put it all in a /test/ dir and move on with your life.